How to return Vue component from the function that should return DOM elements or React components
I am new to Vue, so sorry if I am asking something trivial, maybe I just need a pointer to a proper API.
I have a third-party SDK I can render custom UI by implementing a function that "returns DOM elements or React components". The basic example looks like this:
const renderCustomComponent = () => {
    const parent = document.createElement('div');
    parent.innerHTML = '<h2>Some custom content</h2>';
    return parent;
  };

I also have a Vue component, lets call it MyGreeting.vue:
<script setup lang="ts">
  defineProps<{
    greeting: string;
  }>();
</script>
<template>
  <h2>{{ greeting }}</h2>
</template>

So I would like my renderCustomComponent to load MyGreeting with properties. I.e.:
const renderCustomComponent = () => {
   return // MyGreeting with properties
}

It's also OK if I need to wrap it in a div:
const renderCustomComponent = () => {
    const parent = document.createElement('div');
    // load MyGreeting with properties into parent
    return parent;
  };

How can I do that?

Vue component is gibberish for an API that supports React only. Could be better if it supported custom components aka web components, which Vue can register. This depends on how this SDK is supposed to use an element, and when this function will be called. The question needs to cover this. Considering that an element is supposed to be detached and SDK attaches it somewhere after calling the function, it could be const parent = document.createElement('div'); createApp(MyGreeting).mount(parent); return parent, but under other conditions this won't work well

@EstusFlask yes, that worked, thanks.

@EstusFlask if you write an answer, I will accept it. This question is generic enough I think to be useful for someone else (with caveats that you listed)
